# How can I use iTextSharp to determine a text field's maximum number of characters allowed?

Tags: asp.net, itext

I have a PDF document with a number of text fields, several of which have a maximum length - namely, a maximum number of allowable characters.

Is there a way using iTextSharp to determine this setting? Here's the code I have so far:

```
Dim reader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader("Foobar.pdf")
Dim inputFields As IDictionary(Of String, iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item) = reader.AcroFields.Fields

For Each key As String In inputFields.Keys
    Dim PDFFieldName As String = key
    Dim MaxFieldLength As Integer = ???

    ...
Next
```

I need to set `MaxFieldLength` to the number of allowable characters for the current form field being iterated over.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
    Dim reader As New PdfReader("YourPdf.pdf")
    Dim fields As IDictionary(Of String, iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item) = reader.AcroFields.Fields
    For Each key As String In fields.Keys
        Dim fieldItem = reader.AcroFields.GetFieldItem(key)
        Dim pdfDictionary As PdfDictionary = fieldItem.GetWidget(0)

        Dim pdfFieldName As String = key
        Dim maxFieldLength As Integer = Int32.Parse(pdfDictionary.GetAsNumber(PdfName.MAXLEN).ToString())

        Console.WriteLine("Field={0}, MaxLen={1}", pdfFieldName, maxFieldLength.ToString())
    Next
```

I would like to find detailed docs on the PdfName class.

Comment: Thanks! I won't be back at the client's site to test this until next week, but once I do I'll be sure to let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: Made it out to the client's site yesterday and had the opportunity to implement this code - worked as advertised, thanks!

Comment: The PdfName class mentions looking in the [Pdf Reference Manual](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) - I found the information I was looking for in the Annotations chapter (after a bit of scrolling).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
byte[] Password;

//generates Byte array to unlock PDF
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
Password = encoding.GetBytes("xxxxxxxx");
//PdfReader myReader = new PdfReader();

PdfReader myReader = new PdfReader(file, Password);
PdfStamper myStamp = new PdfStamper(myReader, new FileStream(file + "_TMP", FileMode.Create));
//PdfStamper myStamp = new PdfStamper(myReader, new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create));
AcroFields myFields = myStamp.AcroFields;

string tmpString;

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> de in myFields.Fields)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Processing... " + de.Key + " : " + de.Value.GetWidget(0).Get(PdfName.MAXLEN));
  tmpString = de.Key + " : " + de.Value.GetWidget(0).Get(PdfName.MAXLEN);
}
```